# How to interpret the graph get from a generalized additive model with integrated smoothness estimation?

Tags: r, data-visualization, econometrics, generalized-additive-model

I'm a beginner in econometrics and have to interpret the graph I get after running an nonparametric regression using the package "mgcv" on RStudio (R). We have to use the function "gam()" for it. To begin with and for simplicity, we should regress on only one variable (price of cigarettes).

The formula was:

```
model <- gam(packs~ s(price)).
```

After plotting it I get this graph:[image]

How should I interpret this graph?

Comment: @TonTonFino You will probably get a better response if you show your code and describe your data a bit.

Comment: library(mgcv) # the package for generalized additive models
library(np)  #load nonparametric regression package
library(crs) # load package for categorical regression splines
library(AER) # load AER to get the panel data on cigarette consumption

data("CigarettesSW")
attach(CigarettesSW)

model <- gam(packs~ s(price))  
summary(model)


plot.gam(model)